# Client SSL authentication with NSURLConnection doesn't work on OS X 10.7

Tags: objective-c, macos, ssl, nsurlconnection, nsurlcredential

I'm writing an HTTPS client, which authenticates itself to the server using a certificate in the keychain. For that, I implement connection:willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge: delegate.

Everything works on 10.8, but I'm getting an error on 10.7 - "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made."

I noticed that on 10.8 the delegate gets called twice: first time with NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust method, when with NSURLAuthenticationMethodClientCertificate.

On 10.7 it also gets called twice, but both times with NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust method. And no matter how I respond to it - either by continueWithoutCredentialForAuthenticationChallenge or by setting a credential, returned by [NSURLCredential credentialForTrust - it doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong, and how to get it working on 10.7?

Comment: Did you get it working? I am facing the same problem.

Comment: Nope. Luckily, it works on Mavericks, and 10.7 is a lesser concern now for us.